# Error like "Line 46. parse error, unexpected EQ, expecting SEMICOLON or CLOSEPAR"

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl

my program is

```
entity mult is
    Port ( a,b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (07 downto 0);
           p: out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end mult;

architecture Behavioral of mult is
signal m1,m6,m8:std_logic_vector(7 downto 4);
signal m2,m3,m5,m7:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal m4:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal c,d,x:std_logic;
component fourbitmult 
    Port ( a,b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           p : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;
component csa 
    Port ( a,b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (07 downto 0);
          cin : in  STD_LOGIC='0';
          s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (07 downto 0);
          cout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;
component rca
port ( a,b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           carry : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;
begin
v1:fourbitmult port map(a(3 downto 0),b(3 downto 0),p(3 downto 0),m1(7 downto 4));
v2:fourbitmult port map(a(7 downto 4),b(3 downto 0),m2(7 downto 0));
v3:fourbitmult port map(a(3 downto 0),b(7 downto 4),m3(7 downto 0));
v4:fourbitmult port map(a(7 downto 4),b(7 downto 4),m4(3 downto 0),m8(7 downto 4));
a1:csa port map(m2(7 downto 0),m3(7 downto 0),m5(7 downto 0),c);
a2:csa port map(m1(7 downto 4),m5(7 downto 0),m4(3 downto 0),p(11 downto 4),d);
x<=c or d;
r1:rca port map(m8(7 downto 4),x,p(15 downto 12));


end Behavioral;
```

my syntax is correct.i tried my level best to solve this error.
still i am getting error 
     Line 46. parse error, unexpected EQ, expecting SEMICOLON or CLOSEPAR
what could be wrong?

Comment: My intuition tells me that `cin : in STD_LOGIC='0'` is your problem. It's the only spot you have an equals, or try to do an assignment. I'm guessing you can't do an assignment there, so the `='0'`is unexpected. I don't know the language, so I can't give you a complete answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vhdl 4 bit vedic multiplier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604245/vhdl-4-bit-vedic-multiplier)

Comment: If you find yourself susceptible to the same error repeatedly perhaps you could check for the same cause before posting a question?  (@CreationEdge is mostly correct, the `=` sign should be a variable assignment (`:=`).  See Jyoti's other question with the same error message.  And once again, no the syntax is not correct.

Comment: Actually it is too complecated to resolve the error.plz help me in writting the program.

Comment: There IS no Line 46!

Comment: This isn't the place to ask for someone to do your assignment for you There is no motivation for doing so either, you didn't so much as indicate whether your resolved your previous question, just quit. Under the Help tab, the Tour selection, see [Get answers to practical, detailed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the Help Center, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). CreationEdge pointed to the problem. Your original line 46 should be `cin : in STD_LOGIC := '0'`, (the component declaration for `csa`).

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5 Interface declarations (or -1993 4.3.2) - "If an interface declaration contains a “:=” symbol followed by an expression, the expression is said to be the default expression of the interface object." The `=` symbol by itself is a relational operator (equality), an expression, described in -2008 9.2.3 (-1993 7.2.2).  An equality operator in your original Line 46 is not syntactically correct, while the assignment operator denoting the default expression is.

Comment: And notice that without indicating which line was originally Line 46 as @BrianDrummond indicated, your removing header comments, while commendable doesn't leave you with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i hav tried that 8 bit multiplier as you said for 4 bit multiplier.but unfortunately i failed to resolve that problem.please help me to resolve that error.